# UIView.animate doesn't display view with delay

Tags: ios, swift

I have an AnimationHelper class with this method:

```
func display(view: UIView, withDelay: TimeInterval) {

  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: withDelay, options: .curveEaseIn, animations: {
    view.isHidden = false
  }, completion: nil)
}
```

And call this method from the another class:

```
animationHelper.display(view: labelContainerView, withDelay: 1)
```

and `labelContainerView` should display with a delay but appears immediately.

How can I display it with a delay?

Comment: you can find the list of animatable properties in __[Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/AnimatableProperties/AnimatableProperties.html)__, but briefly the `BOOL` properties cannot be animated.

Comment: holex, ozgur - thank you!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`isHidden` is not an animatable property. You can set `alpha` to 1.0 to make it appear with animation:

```
view.alpha = 1.0
```